# CSS Ignore one element when determining parent size

Tags: html, css

Basically, how can I achieve this:

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div class="ignoreWidth" style="width: 20px;">20px</div>
    <div style="width: 4px;">4px</div>
    <div style="width: 8px;">8px</div>
</div>
<!-- outerDiv.style.width == 8px -->
```

Without hard-coding the width for the outer div.

Edit: 
The `position: absolute` worked for fixing the width problem, but then all the other elements are moved under it.  Is there any way to avoid that without padding?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? You want outerDiv to be 8px wide but you don't want to declare a width of 8px?

Comment: I want it to determine the width of the outer div from the children like it normally would, except it should ignore the first one when doing this calculation.

Comment: @Temani Afif Did you seriously mark my 5-year-old question as a duplicate of a one-day-old question?

Comment: yes, because the time doesn't matter, only the quality of the answers matter and the other answer in the duplicate question solves your issue because as you stated: position absolute doesn't fix your issue (related : https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/386331 / https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286721/8620333)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make the css `position` attribute for outerDiv `relative` and the `position` for the class `ignoreWidth` `absolute` and set to 0, 0

this should position the first inner div in the top left of the outer div and use it's own height and width properties

in your css file for this page:

```
#outerDiv {
  position:relative;
}
.ignoreWidth {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take it out of the document flow with

```
.ignoreWidth{
  position:absolute;
}
```

.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to set the width of outerDiv equal to the width of the second widest child div at the time of rendering.