# How to ignore a certain element when determining parent's size

Tags: html, css

I have a div which is only as wide as its contents, but I'm trying to make it so that a certain element is ignored when determining the div's size.

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="ignore" style="width: 20px"></div>
    <div style="width: 10px"></div>
</div>
```

I want to make it so that the width of the parent div is 10px

As suggested by [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435217/css-ignore-one-element-when-determining-parent-size), I tried adding `position:absolute` to `.ignore`, but this takes it out of the document flow, which is not what I want. Is there some way to keep `.ignore` in the document flow, but have it overflow past the 10px width?

**This is what I want:**

[image: This]

**Not this:**

[image: this]

Comment: This site has some really helpful info on extending a div beyond it's parent container ---  https://www.modus-made.com/en/Ideas/CSS-Tricks-Expanding-Beyond-a-Parent-div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a big negative margin to the `ignore` element while setting the width.

```css
#parent {
  background:red;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#parent > div {
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.ignore {
  margin-right:-500px;
  
  /*to illustrate*/
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {width:10px;}
  to {width:100px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="ignore"></div>
    <div style="width: 30px"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div class="ignore"></div>
    <div style="width: 30px"></div>
</div>
```

Or use only the negative margin to set the width. Note that the final width will be the sum of the biggest width inside the parent + the margin you set (not only the margin)

```css
#parent {
  background:red;
  padding:5px;
  display:inline-block;
}
#parent > div {
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

.ignore {
  /*to illustrate*/
  animation:change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {margin-right:-10px;}
  to {margin-right:-100px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="ignore"></div>
    <div style="width: 30px"></div>
    <div></div>
    <div style="width: 40px"></div>
    <div class="ignore"></div>
    <div style="width: 30px"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ignore {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="ignore" style="width: 20px"></div>
    <div style="width: 10px"></div>
</div>
```

This would do the magic. Tell me if it works;

Comment: he said: **I tried adding position:absolute to .ignore, but this takes it out of the document flow, which is not what I want.**

Comment: Check his images added to the question

Comment: display:inline-block lets the parent snap to its remaining width

Comment: This solution will not work for multiple bars and it's hardly demonstrating anything at all, and if you are going to answer, at least provide some explanation of what you did. Please read [answer] for more details

Answer (score 0):

In case you only want one of the divs to have the desired result and want the div with .ignore class to be of a higher width. You may use the below  code.

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="ignore">Ignore</div>
  <div style="width: 60px">Normal</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
 background:red;
 padding:10px;
 overflow:visible;
 max-width:60px;
 }

#parent > div {
  height:20px;
  background:blue;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.ignore {
  width:100px;
 }
```

I have used the overflow:visible property and set it's max-width of 60px (which s the width of all our divs without the .ignore class.) to the parent element, and given the div with .ignore class the width of my choice.

Here is the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NmoVxw

Hope this helps. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this doesn't work when the width of the parent div is unknown...

Comment: Ya in that case, the parent will take the width of its child with larger width. Let me try some other way.

Comment: @Param: A parent div is a block level element, Right? Means it will itself first occupy all the width of the browser. First to make it of some fixed width either we need to set its width to some value (like I did), or make the parent div inline-block for it to be of a fixed width. Right? So which one are you using.? If you give it a fixed with, with overflow visible, then my answer meets the requirement., but in case you are using inline-block, for it, then it is not working as per your need.

Comment: Hmmm, I read the message late, Great that it's solved, So is it the Answer by @temani afif, or some other answer, can you share the answer please. I would like to have a look please. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another idea, change the scale instead of width.

```css
#parent {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#parent>div {
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.ignore {
  transform-origin: left;
  animation: change 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scaleX(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="ignore"></div>
  <div style="width: 30px"></div>
  <div></div>
  <div style="width: 40px"></div>
  <div class="ignore"></div>
  <div style="width: 30px"></div>
</div>
```